# django startproject exceptio in windows xp

Tags: python, django, windows

I am using python 3.3 on window xp.
PATH variable is `";C:\Python33;C\Python33\Scripts;C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\”`

when i create new project it gives an exception.
[image]
Please tell what i missed?

Comment: You can copy text from the Windows console using the `[-]` menu at the top left. *Please* do copy the text into this post instead of using a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade to Django 1.5c1 (still in development). You appear to be running a development version that predates even 1.5a1. The error you see is due to a syntax change between the major Python versions and was [fixed 9 months ago](https://github.com/django/django/commit/3904b74a3f2f92fefe1d39281ed683c52f2fef03).

Or better still, use Python 2.7 instead; even in Django 1.5 the Python 3 support is labelled as experimental.

Comment: @akaIDIOT: Actually, that particular exception clause was fixed 9 months ago, well before the release of 1.5a1. Something is b0rken there.